# Discord.py : Slash Command working but simultaneously giving and error

Tags: python, discord.py

I have just come back to coding in Discord.py and I have this error.
[image]

So basically I am unable to figure out the reason. The code is here:

```
@cerium.slash_command(name="avatar", description="get the avatar for the user you want to")
async def avatar(ctx, *, member : discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.send(member.display_avatar)
```

Comment: What is `cerium`?
You must respond to the interaction, so Discord knows that the interaction was successfully responded to.

Comment: @Hazzu `cerium` is the bot variable. And what do you mean by responding to interaction?

Comment: An interaction needs a response, you can't simply use it as if it was a regular context, each time a user send a "slash command" you will need to send a response to this *interaction*. If you want a solution to your problem use `await interaction.response.send_message(member.display.avatar)` instead of your ctx.send.
Remember context != interaction.

Comment: @Paul is there a reason why you guys always respond via comments instead of giving an answer? Because from the discord.py front page it always looks like the question is unanswered but its actually answered already..

Comment: @sicco14 This user does not appear to be using discord.py. I found this `cerium` name strange and also the way he defined the command using `@slash_command` instead of `@bot.tree.command()` or `@app_commands.command()`. So I'm using the comments to clarify doubts about the author's question, because it is not clear and lacks information.

Comment: @Hazzu I can add the whole code for you to understand and I haven't worked on this library for quite a while now, if you also suggest some docs for me to work on this, it'll be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must respond to the interaction, so Discord knows that the interaction was successfully responded to. Also pay attention to the correct way to create application commands using the `@bot.tree.command()` decorator:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intentes.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.tree.command(name="avatar", description="get the avatar for the user you want to")
async def avatar(interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member = None):
    avatar_url = member.display_avatar.url
    await interaction.response.send_message(avatar_url)
```

Recommended reading: [Slash Commands and you](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f).